# SQL Server beginner: How to update table data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I'm still learning SQL. I have question about updating table. How can I update my table based on other table? Please see the example below:

```
create table batch_info (
    batch_key int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
    batch_num int not null,
    batch_name varchar(50) null,
    batch_start datetime null,
    batch_end datetime null,
    table_name varchar(50) null,
    insert_rows int null
)
go

insert into batch_info (batch_num, batch_name, batch_start)
    values ('32', 'Batch_to_insert_rows', '20110414')
go

select * from batch_info

create table ref_table (
    bat_num int not null,
    bat_end_date datetime null,
    bat_table_name varchar(50) null,
    bat_ins_rows int null,
)
go

insert into ref_table 
    values  ('32','20110414 02:12:00.000','Table1','10'),
            ('32','20110414 02:12:00.000','Table2','33'),
            ('32','20110414 02:12:00.000','Table3','12') 

select * from ref_table

--How can I update batch_info table to get this info?
select 
bi.batch_key, 
bi.batch_num, 
bi.batch_name,
bi.batch_start,
rt.bat_end_date,
rt.bat_table_name, 
rt.bat_ins_rows
 from batch_info as bi
inner join ref_table as rt on bi.batch_num = rt.bat_num
```

**Edit:** batch key is surrogate so it should be incremental, not (1, 1, 1) as in my join query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that combinations of batch_num and bat_end_date are unique, then this should do the trick:

```
update  batch_info 
set     batch_end = rt.bat_end_date,
        table_name = rt.bat_table_name,
        insert_rows = rt.bat_ins_rows 
from    batch_info bi
        inner join ref_table rt on rt.bat_num = bi.batch_num 
        inner join 
        (
            select  bat_num,
                    MIN(bat_end_date) as min_bat_end_date
            from    ref_table 
        ) oldest on oldest.bat_num = rt.bat_num 
                    and oldest.min_bat_end_date = rt.bat_end_date 
where   bi.batch_end is null

insert into batch_info 
(batch_num, batch_name, batch_start, batch_end, table_name, insert_rows)
select  bi.batch_num,
        bi.batch_name,
        bi.batch_start,
        rt.bat_end_date,
        rt.bat_table_name,
        rt.bat_ins_rows 
from    batch_info bi
        inner join ref_table rt on rt.bat_num = bi.batch_num 
where   not exists 
        (
            select   * 
            from     batch_info e 
            where    e.batch_num = bi.batch_num 
                     and e.batch_end = rt.bat_end_date
        )
```

If another combination of values establishes uniqueness, then those can be added to `oldest` in the first query, and `e` in the second.

I agree with @Jim that this should be split into two tables. The difficulty of performing this operation is a harbinger of the difficulties that this design is going to create. You are trying to put two different things (batches and batch runs) into a single table, and that is never a good idea.

Comment: @Jeffrey +1 for you for answering the question without a cursor (ick) like I suggested. But as we both agree, it should be two tables.

Comment: Thanks. First statement generates an error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column 'ref_table.bat_num' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And the insert statement does not seem to insert anything in this example.

Comment: @jrara - It doesn't do anything on that example, because, clearly, bat_num + end_date does not define unique records. You never specified in the question what does identify unique records. I said in my answer, those things need to be added to the query to make it work. I could probably take another guess from the example data, but only you know the correct answer to that, so my guessing would be pointless.

Comment: Regarding the other error, I left out a GROUP BY. I must've been in a hurry! Just put, "group by rt.bat_num" after "from ref_table" in the derived table expression (subquery) of the update statement.

Comment: @Jefferey L Whitledge: Ok, thank you for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into batch_info
SELECT batch_num, batch_name, batch_start,
bat_end, bat_table_name, bat_ins_rows
FROM batch_info inner join ref_table
on batch_info.batch_num = ref_table.bat_num

delete from batch_info
where batch_end is null
```

EDIT: The `INSERT` is generating all matching rows & inserting it afresh. New Identity values will be added to those. The existing row (with other fields null) is used for `INSERT` statement & later deleted using the 2nd statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to point you to the [Merge Statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), but I don't think this can be done with that either. I think you are going to be stuck using a [Cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

With that said and not knowing your existing requirements, it *really should be two tables*. Pushing all into one table is denormalizing the table design.

Comment: I'm not working with operational database. This batch_info table is a log table in data warehouse, so I think its fine to denormalize this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the batch_info.batch_key field autoincrement.

```
create table batch_info (
batch_key int identity(1, 1) not null primary key, -- <<- make autoincrement.
...
```